The number $1^1 + 3^3 + 5^5 + .. + (2^n - 1)^{2^n-1}$ is a multiple of $2^n$ but not a multiple of $2^{n+1}$
Prove that for all $n>1$ the number $1^1 + 3^3 + 5^5 + .. + (2^n - 1)^{2^n-1}$ is a multiple of $2^n$ but not a multiple of $2^{n+1}$.
Proof: Let $$S_n=1^1 + 3^3 + 5^5 + .. + (2^n - 1)^{2^n-1}$$
We will prove by induction on $n$ that $ 2^ {n} $ divides $ S_ {n} $ and $ 2^ {n+1} $ does not divide $S_n$.The case $n = 2$ is clear, so assume that $ S_ {n} $ = $ 2^ {n}m $  for some odd number $m$.Note that
$$ S_ {n+1}  =  S_ {n}  + \sum _ {k=1, 2 \nmid k}^ {2^{n}-1}  (k+2^ {n})^ {k+2^ {n}} \tag{1}$$
The binomial formula combined with theorem 2.31(For any positive odd integer $k$, $k^{2^n}≡ 1 (mod 2^{n+2})$) yields
$$ (k+2^ {n})^ {k+2^ {n}}  =  (k+2^ {n})^ {2^n} (k+2^ {n})^ {k}  ≡  (k+2^ {n})^ {k}  
≡  k^ {k}  +  k^ {k-1} 2^ {n}\binom{k}1=  k^ {k}  (1+  2^ {n}  )  (  mod 2^ {n+2}  )$$
Thus $$ S_ {n+1}  ≡  S_ {n}  +(1+  2^ {n}  )  \cdot \sum _ {k=1, 2 \nmid k}^ {2^{n}-1}  k^ {k} 
=  2(1+  2^ {n-1}  )S_n=  2^ {n+1}  m(1+  2^ {n-1}  )(  mod2^ {n+2}  )$$
Since m is odd, it follows that $ 2^ {n+1 } $ divides $ S_ {n+1} $ but $ 2^ {n+2} $ does not divide
$n+1$, which establishes the inductive step.
From Number Theory:Concepts And Problems by Titu Andreescu
My question: What could be the logic and thought to notice $(1)$, how
$$(2^{n+1} - 1)^{2^{n+1}-1}=\sum _ {k=1, 2 \nmid k}^ {2^{n}-1}  (k+2^ {n})^ {k+2^ {n}} $$Could someone explain ?
Thanks in advance:)

That is not the logic. How many additional terms are there in $S_{n+1}$ but not in $S_n$. Note each $S_n$ must end in a number of form $2^n - 1$. So given that $S_n$ ends with $2^n-1$, we now need to add all numbers from $(2^n+1)^{2^n+1}$ till $ (2^{n+1}-1)^{2^{n+1} - 1}$
